# Zend framework view_manager

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have new module in application named Product, i create config/module.config.php with this code:

```
 return array(
  'controllers' => array(
      'invokables' => array(
          'Product\Controller\Product' => 'Product\Controller\ProductController',
       ),
  ),
  'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'product' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/product[/][:action][/][:id]',
                    'constraits' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Product\Controller\Product',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
  ),                 

  'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'product/product/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/product/product/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
          'product' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

routing for layout is working but for index no and i dont know why. 
my route dir is on next picture:
http://tinypic.com/r/2ebzxo4/8

Comment: This looks like Zend 2. If it is so, maybe would be good to better tag question.

Comment: 1) Have you actually added the module `Product` to the `modules` key in `/config/application.config.php` ? 2) "routing for layout is working but for index no" It might help if you explained how it's not working, are you getting an error message for example, and if so, what?

Answer (score -1):

Change your onBootstrap method in module.php like this:

```
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

        $sharedEventManager->attach(
            __NAMESPACE__, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function($e) {
                $controller = $e->getTarget();
                $controllerName = $controller->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller');

                if (in_array($controllerName, array('Product\Controller\Product')) {
                    $controller->layout('product/product/index');
                }
        });
    }
```

But it is only necessary to substitute instead controller action.